# Magento 2 add extra image Type/Role

Tags: magento2, product, image, role, custom-field

How can we add extra field in image role in product page admin panel.

I want to add new field same as thumbnail in Image role popup.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e467tlo04

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Yoi can close this question after mark as accepted.

Answer (score 12):

You have to just add image role using create image attribute from

> Stores -> Attribute -> Product

Click on Create new attribute.

**Set Catalog Input type for store owner is Media Image**

Save Attribute.
[image]

**Now set above attribute in Attribute Set like default.**

> Run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: How to get or load this image/image type on category page?

Comment: You also need to add the newly created attribute to relevant attribute sets (Stores > Attribute> Attribute Sets)

Answer (score -3):

This command solved my issue:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```