# How to get url of last image from $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image') Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, image

I am trying to get URL of image of last image.

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')
            ->setImageFile($block->getProductForThumbnail()->getImage())
            ->resize(165, 165)->getUrl(); ?>
```

This code gives me url of first image, How can i get url for the last image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using the above logic.

Remember that the default image roles define a single product image as Base, Small, Thumbnail.

I recommend that you add another custom image role

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/153425/70343

Set the last image as this custom role.  Then update your template logic where required to get image based on this custom role instead.

*update*

If response to your comment

See here how they've put together block logic and render small image. What defines small image is because of the dimensions.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241661/70343

I still think you are going to have to create and use a custom image role.

Comment: Xigne , How can i get small_image in magento 2, the image which i want to show is small_image